# Intuitive explanation why if $P$ is a subspace of linear space $L$, then $L/P$ is not a subspace of $L$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there an intuitive explanation of why:

if $P$ is a subsppace of linear space $L$, then $L/P$ is not a subspace of $L$. I know that it is true, but it is counter intuitive to me.

Comment: It is always isomorphic to a subspace of $L$. It depends on your definition of subspace.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a concrete example, and perhaps all will be clear. For $L$, let's take the good old-fashioned Euclidean plane $\Bbb R^2$. For $P$, let's take a line of slope $0 \leq m < \infty$, so:

$P = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: y = mx\}$.

It should be clear that $P$ is indeed a subspace:

$(0,0) \in P$, since $0 = m\cdot 0$.

If $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in P$, so that $y_1 = mx_1$ and $y_2 = mx_2$, then

$(x_1,y_1) + (x_2,y_2) = (x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2) \in P$, since:

$y_1 + y_2 = mx_1 + mx_2 = m(x_1 + mx_2)$.

Finally, if $c \in \Bbb R$, and $(x,y) \in P$, then $c(x,y) = (cx,cy) \in P$, because:

$cy = c(mx) = m(cx)$ (note how the commutativity of our field is used here).

Now, I claim that any coset $(x_0,y_0) + P$ of $L/P$ is a line $y = mx + b$, where:

$(0,b) \in (x_0,y_0) + P$. It's always good to see such things proved at least once.

So let's assume $(x_1,y_1)$ satisfies $y_1 = mx_1 + b$. Note that since $(0,b) \in (x_0,y_0) + P$,

we know $(y_0 - b,x_0 - 0) \in P$, that is: $y_0 = mx_0 + b$. Thus:

$(x_1,y_1) - (x_0,y_0) = (x_1-x_0,y_1-y_0) = (x_1-x_0,mx_1 + b - mx_0 - b)$

$= (x_1-x_0,m(x_1 - x_0))$, which is clearly in $P$. So any point on our line $y = mx + b$

is in the coset $(x_0,y_0) + P$. Now suppose that $(x_2,y_2) \in (x_0,y_0) + P$.

Then $(x_2 - x_0,y_2 - y_0) \in P$, so: $y_2 - y_0 = m(x_2 - x_0)$, equivalently:

$y_2 = mx_2 - mx_0 + y_0 = mx_2 - mx_0 + mx_0 + b = mx_2 + b$, so $(x_2,y_2)$ lies on our line.

So here's the thing: $L/P$ is a collection of parallel LINES (all with slope $m$), it's "points" aren't even elements of $L$. Recall a subspace of $L$ is a subset of $L$, whereas $L/P$ is actually a subset of the POWER SET of $L$ (its elements are subsets of $L$). It's "on the wrong level" to be a subspace of $L$.

Of course, it *is* suspiciously similar to the subspace:

$\{(0,y): y \in \Bbb R\}$ of $\Bbb R^2$ (we can "add two parallel lines", by adding their $y$-intercepts, and ignoring the slope information). This is because:

$[(0,b_1) + P] + [(0,b_2) + P] = (0,b_1+b_2) + P$

but, a "line of lines" is not the same thing as the plane: the plane has two dimensions, our "line of lines" has only one.

Answer (score 0):

The members of $L/P$ are not members of $L$, they are equivalence classes of members of $L$.

Comment: thank you, I am sure that you are correct, but it is not really an intuitive explanation for me.

Comment: For example, suppose $L$ is the plane $\mathbb R^2$ and $P = \{(x,0): x \in \mathbb R\}$ is the $x$ axis.  Each member of $L/P$ is a horizontal line $\{(x,y): x \in \mathbb R\}$ for a particular $y$.

Comment: and why exactly these horizontal lines are not a subspace of L?

Comment: The members of $L$ are points, not lines.